# jQuery - how to add class to container and remove on click outside

Tags: html, jquery, onclick

I need a simple script. I have list:

```
<ul>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
</ul>
```

By clicking `<li>` I need to add class active to clicked element. On click outside remove class active. On click another `<li>` element remove class active from first clicked and add class active to clicked element.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very very basic stuff you shud go and study jQuery first. You can add/remove class like this

```js
$('li').click(function(event){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>teste1</li>
</ul>
```

Take a look at https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: You are right, this is basic. My problem is how to remove class active by clicking outside `ul`.

Comment: i have updated with the click outside. You need to take look at the 'jquery selectors'

Comment: You should mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the `<li>` element and set an event for it. In my opinion you should have a **class** for your `<li>` element so you dont find another unwanted elements.

```js
$('li').on('click', function(elem)  {

    $('li').each(function (elem) { 
        $(this).removeClass('active') 
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok, thx. but how to remove class active by clicking outside `<ul>`?